# Azure Web App deployment from private Github Repository with Terraform

Tags: github, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I have used Terraform to create a Linux Web App in Azure. I want to deploy to this web app using CI from my own private GitHub repository, as it allows you to do when setting up a web app through the Azure Portal. I currently have done this:

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "dev_plan" {
  provider            = azurerm.dev
  name                = "app-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.dev_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.dev_rg.name
  sku_name            = "B1"
  os_type             = "Linux"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "dev_service" {
  provider            = azurerm.dev
  name                = "api"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.dev_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.dev_rg.name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.dev_plan.id
  https_only          = true

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version = "7.0"
    }
  }  
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "dev_source" {
  provider = azurerm.dev
  app_id   = azurerm_linux_web_app.dev_service.id
  repo_url = "REPO_URL"
  branch   = "main"

  github_action_configuration {
    code_configuration {
      runtime_stack   = "dotnetcore"
      runtime_version = "7.0"
    }
  }
}
```

This creates the app service correctly, but fails on the `azurerm_app_service_source_control` step due to the following error:

```
Error: creating Source Control configuration for Web App: (Site Name "api" / Resource Group "dev"): web.AppsClient#UpdateSourceControl: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="NotFound" Message="Cannot find User with name 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000." Details=[{"Message":"Cannot find User with name 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000."},{"Code":"NotFound"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"NotFound","ExtendedCode":"51004","Message":"Cannot find User with name 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.","MessageTemplate":"Cannot find {0} with name {1}.","Parameters":["User","00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]}}]
```

I assume I am missing some kind of authentication step for the GitHub deployment, but cannot figure out what from the documentation. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Marcin for an approach using GitHub Action workflows. In addition to that, I found another approach which is detailed below.

In order to deploy an Azure Linux web app from private GitHub repository, alongside the source control resource you must have a GitHub token to allow communication between terraform configuration and GitHub.

This can be done using [`azurerm_source_control_token`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/source_control_token) resource in terraform.

To obtain the GitHub token for authentication, follow below path:

*GitHub Profile >> Go to Settings >> Developer Settings >> Personal Access Tokens >> Tokens (classic) >> Generate token by providing the necessary permissions.*

[image]

*Once the token has generated, I tried below code to achieve the requirement and the deployment worked as expected.*

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
    features{}
}
variable "github_auth" {
  type        = string
  description = "Token for authorization"
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Jahnavi"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "appservice-jahplan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "westeurope"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "linux-app" {
  name                = "linux-web-jahapp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "westeurope"
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
  https_only          = true
  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version = "7.0"
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "source_control" {
  app_id                 = azurerm_linux_web_app.linux-app.id
  repo_url               = "https://github.com/xxxx/newj.git"
  branch                 = "main"
  use_manual_integration = true
}
resource "azurerm_source_control_token" "source_token" {
  type         = "GitHub"
  token        = var.github_auth
  token_secret = var.github_auth
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

*Verify the deployment center once the web app is deployed as shown:*

[image]

Refer [blog](https://dennizsvens.medium.com/deploying-an-azure-web-app-with-a-git-deployment-source-using-terraform-8823b56ac2b7) by @Denniz Svens for the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Azure Authentication on Github actions using `GitHub Secrets` as explained in [GitHub Actions Workflows for Terraform](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/terraform-github-actions) for Azure.